# How to define the ActionMethod and Controller name inside Html Input

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Input field inside my asp.net mvc:-

```
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn" />
```

But how i can specify that in case a user click on this button to return back to the Index action method of the current controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a form (GET method, and make it "submit" instead of "reset", since it's basically just a link back to the Index page):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type='submit' value='Cancel' class='btn' />
}
```